# Moving object to click even X and Y with canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I was wondering is it possible to move a shape on the canvas to specific coordinates on the canvas from another set of coordinates. In this case is it possible to get the location of a mouse click and create an object that moves to that point over a specific amount of time? Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: Yes, all of that is possible. Perhaps you should look at some of the documentation on canvas.

Comment: For example, http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/html5-canvas/4822/animation/20153/animate-from-x0-y0-to-x1-y1

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is too broad. I am using a custom closure reason in order to suggest that broad questions can now be closed as duplicates of Documentation Examples. http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/html5-canvas/4822/animation/20153/animate-from-x0-y0-to-x1-y1

Comment: What you want to ask, is this:
Is it possible to detect an **mouse dbclick event** somewhere **inside a HTML5 canvas**, **get the X,Y mouse click coordinates** from that event,  make an object present in the canvas **move towards** the mouse click point, **step by step**, using a **time interval** (setInterval, or requestAnimationframe), until it reaches the same point where the mouse was clicked. 

Now, do you think you have enough information to start doing it, or to search what you need to do it?

Answer (score 1):

```
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
<script>
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

var x2=100,y2=100;
var dx=0,dy=0;
var counter=10;

canvas.width = canvas.height = 256;
var shape = {x:100, y:100, width : 50, height : 30};

function clear() {
  ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3)';
  ctx.fillRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
}

function draw(){
if(counter>0){
    shape.x=shape.x+dx;
    shape.y=shape.y+dy;
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,256,256);
    ctx.fillStyle = "red";
    ctx.strokeStyle = "black";
        ctx.fillRect(shape.x, shape.y, shape.width, shape.height);
        ctx.strokeRect(shape.x, shape.y, shape.width,shape.height);
    counter--;
    setTimeout(draw,20)
    }
}

canvas.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    clear();
    x2=e.clientX;
    y2=e.clientY;

    dx=(x2-shape.x)/10;
    dy=(y2-shape.y)/10;
    counter=10;
    draw();
});

draw();

</script>
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/xutawoxv/1/